# Local Thresholding or Binarization of Text in an image

Tags: c#, image-processing, ocr, image-recognition, aforge

Im developing an application to exctract text in C# in different light condition.

My problem is that sometimes there are different brightness levels in the image, like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/NJ2XTrn.png?1]

So i cant utilize a pre-calculated threshold for the whole image, or i will loose some letters.

Im searching an algorithm/snippet/function or else, that can apply the right Threshold/Binarization to the image.

I founded thhis [BradleyLocalThresholding](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/0ad5b988-5613-d62a-22a9-cf41e39c139f.htm) in AForge, is better than other non adaptive methods, but it loose some details. ( for example the G in the image become an O )

Anyone can suggest to me a better way?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the 't' percentage? Perhaps you could try several values and use the consensus on what letter it is. *Disclamer: I've never done any reall image processing and only read the remarks on the link you posted.*

Comment: The best t value that i have tried, take most of the letters good, BUT the 'G' become an 'O' (So add too much) and the 'L' become an 'I' (so subtract too much).
I have played with the window size, but with no results.

Answer (score 2):

yes, use niblack (opencv has it as a function) - basically it uses the local average to construct a variable theshold. it works best for OCR. depending on the image resolution you might also want to bicubically upsample by a factor of 2x or 3x BEFORE thresholding.

Comment: Hi, can you show where is the niblack or the bicubical upsamle functions in OpenCV??
I have searched in its documentation online but with no result.

Comment: cv::adaptiveThreshold() using type ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN and resize using cv::resize with type INTER_CUBIC

Answer (score 2):

Its quite difficult since the quality of your images are so low, but you could try an iterative global thresholding approach as follows:

1. Randomly select an initial estimate threshold T (usually as the mean).
2. Segment the signal using T, which will yield two groups, G1 consisting of all points with values<=T and G2 consisting of points with value>T.
3. Compute the average distance between points of G1 and T, and points of G2 and T.
4. Compute a new threshold value T=(M1+M2)/2
5. Repeat steps 2 through 4 until the change of T is smaller enough.

The trick is not to apply it to the whole image, but to break up the image into blocks of (for example) 5x5 and apply it to the blocks individually which would give you:

[image]

Below is an implementation in R which I'm sure you could reproduce

```
getT = function(y){
  t = mean(y)

  mu1 = mean(y[y>=t])
  mu2 = mean(y[y 1){
      cmu1 = mean(y[y>=t])
      cmu2 = mean(y[y 1 & cmu1 == mu1 & cmu2 == mu2){
      print(paste('done t=', t))
      return(t)
      break;
    }else{
      mu1 = cmu1 
      mu2 = cmu2
      t = (mu1 + mu2)/2
      print(paste('new t=', t))
    }
    i = i+1
  }
}


r = seq(1, nrow(image), by=5)
c = seq(1, ncol(image), by=5)
r[length(r)] = nrow(image)
c[length(c)] = ncol(image)
y = image
for(i in 2:length(r) ){
  for(j in 2:length(c) ){
    block = image[r[i-1]:r[i], c[j-1]:c[j]]
    t = getT(block)
    y[r[i-1]:r[i], c[j-1]:c[j]] = (block>t)+0
  }
}

display(y)
```

Comment: Very nice example, but i dont think is enough for the robust character recognition. The results that i have with the BradleyLocalThreshold are far away better at the moment.

Comment: Fair enough :-) Is there a reason the images are so low quality?

Comment: I agree, image quality is too low, could be probably better with easy effort by changing capture methods.

Answer (score 0):

The other option besides a local threshold would be to adjust for the varying illumination.  There are methods that attempt to correct the illumination and make it uniform across the image.  You could then use a constant threshold, or continue to use a local threshold, with perhaps better success.  If the images are like the one you show, then you could use the brighter squares around the letters as the key to adjusting the illumination.

Comment: illumination correction also uses local average so no different from niblack, except it requires an extra step. so really no point if the only thing you are looking for is OCR'ed text.

Comment: Illumination can be applied with a macro view as distortions are gradual and continuous across the image.  It can reduce the variance in the local region in an non-uniform way prior to applying an adaptive threshold.